# Nextjs routing issue: superior param is weird

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-router

I have a project using nextjs v12

I have 2 routes that are overlapping in a weird way.

1. `/:academy/:course`
2. `/questions/:id`

when I load `/questions/1` it works as expected
when I load `/mit/math` it works as expected

### The issue:

when I redirect from `/questions/1` to `/questions/2`,
it loads, you guessed it, the other route! (`/:academy/:course`)
and more, when I refresh the page (after the redirect) it will load the `/questions/:id`!!!

### I tried

- check for miss spelling
- make `/questions/:id` -> `/aquestions/:id`

so, do you know a way to solve this issue?

thanks.

## Solved

it was `/q/:id` and I renamed it to `/q/:id`.
and because it's with ssr (I think), I had to clear the cache and restart the project.

Comment: This should not happen, because according to official nextJS docs, 


> Predefined routes take precedence over dynamic routes, and dynamic
> routes over catch all routes.

https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Can you please share the code how you are redirecting, to help you better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not happen, because according to official nextJS docs,

> Predefined routes take precedence over dynamic routes and dynamic
> routes over catch-all routes.

https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

In this case, it looks like we are trying to use 2 partial dynamic path, that is why nextJS is not able to figure out the correct path, you can add rewrite rule to always send `/questions/*` paths to `/questions/:id`

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites

Can you please share the code how you are redirecting, to help you better?